# Deeply Nested resources Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for, nested-resources

I'm struggling to get this working, I've read a lot but couldn't find whats the problem here.

routes.rb

```
  resources :scripts do
    resources :reviews
    resources :issues do
      resources :comments
    end
  end
```

comments_migration

```
create_table :comments do |t|
  t.integer :issue_id
  t.integer :user_id
  t.text :body

  t.timestamps
end
```

controller action

```
  def create
    @issue = Issue.find(params[:issue_id])
    @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.issue_id = @issue.id

    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def new
    @issue = Issue.find(params[:issue_id])
    @comment = current_user.comments.new
    @comment.issue_id = @issue.id
  end
```

Now in my `Issues/Show` view i want to add the form for adding a comment:

```
<%= form_for [@issue, @comment] do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Routes:

```
                          POST   /scripts/:script_id/issues/:issue_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
 new_script_issue_comment GET    /scripts/:script_id/issues/:issue_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
edit_script_issue_comment GET    /scripts/:script_id/issues/:issue_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
     script_issue_comment GET    /scripts/:script_id/issues/:issue_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                          PATCH  /scripts/:script_id/issues/:issue_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                          PUT    /scripts/:script_id/issues/:issue_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                          DELETE /scripts/:script_id/issues/:issue_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
            script_issues GET    /scripts/:script_id/issues(.:format)                             issues#index
```

Which gives me `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`.

Although the request info shows:

```
{"action"=>"show", "controller"=>"issues", "script_id"=>"10", "id"=>"8"}
```

Do i have to include a `:script_id` also to the comments?

What am i missing here?

Comment: If you're getting the error on the `show` action, it would be helpful to see the controller code for it.

Comment: I'm trying to call the `Comments` form in the `Issues` Show View.. You mean the show action from `Issues` ?

Comment: Yes, the `show` action from the Issues controller

Comment: The show action has not something in it.. Do i need to declare it there too ? (Pardon me if this is stupid, i'm still learning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple `form_for` to create the Comment:

```
form_for @issue.comments.build, url: script_issue_comments_path(params[:script_id], @issue) do |f|
  f.text_area :body
  f.submit "save"
end
```

Comment: Cheers Mat, This gives me `undefined method `issue_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fe4f20c36c0>:0x007fe4f20c2888>`, Did i miss something ?

Comment: Does `shallow` make things easier or messier ? Should i go with shallow: true ?

Comment: Try using this: `form_for @issue, url: script_issue_path(@issue.script, @issue)` But I don't think you should do it, I think that Rails is supposed to guess this path himself...

Comment: Same output :/ Do i have to include the script_id also ?? Script > Issue > Comment

Comment: Does the error comes from the same line as the `form_for`? And yes as it is 2 nested resources, you need the ID of the 2 resources

Comment: Ok' so i think there is the problem, i don't specify anywhere the script_id .. (I restarted the Server and It worked, only that the comments are not created.. Form Works but nothing gets in)

Comment: What are the params given to the create action of the IssuesController?

Comment: Hey yoshiji, up for a quick chat ? => http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54897/regex-craziness

Answer (score 1):

You are missing that form is being build upon a `new` action, not on `create`. You need to declare those variables there as well.

Comment: Do i have to include the :script_id too ? I have declared the variables in the `New Action` as well.. The same output.

Comment: If this from is displayed on a show action, you need to set it there.

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because a parameter in form_for is nil. You should initialize it in your show action. You do not need script_id

```
class IssuesController < ApplicationController
    def show
     ..
     @comment = @issue.comments.build
     ..
end
```

Fix for undefined path error. You will need to modify form_for slightly.

```
<% @form_for @comment, url: script_issue_comments_path(@issue.script_id, @issue) do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

Comment: I initialized it in my `New` Action. Still the same

Comment: I didn't notice that you are trying to do it in Issues show page, I have edit my answer, try if it helps

Comment: undefined method `issue_comments_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fe4ed735878>:0x007fe4ed145198> Still :/

Comment: Okay, that's because your issues are nested within scripts. So in this case you will probably need script_id in the url. There is a work around, I will edit my response